# What is the value of using Hibernate's multiple persistence units

Tags: hibernate

I can't understand the value of using Hibernate's multiple persistence units.   What are the use cases that it was designed for?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, they're most frequently used in cases where the applications uses multiple databases or even database servers.

Comment: as a single pojo? or using multiple datasource in single instance of Hibernate?